# Non-pejorative term for 'alcohol aficionado'?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology

Is there a non-pejorative term analogous to "foodie" but in the context of alcoholic drinks?  Everything that comes to mind suggests some form of alcoholism or affinity for binge-drinking.

More concretely, I am looking for a term that describes a person that enjoys making or trying new, possibly eclectic drinks, but is not interested in doing so solely for the buzz.

"Foodie" almost fits, but it seems too broad.

Comment: *Foodie* is not formal. *Gourmet* and *Epicurean* are the formal words related to connoisseurs of food and drink.

Comment: Also *foodie* is by no means "non-pejorative", outside the endless stream of facetiously-titled *Foodies guide to [some city]* beloved of the publishing industry. In common parlance for many people, [Foodies are all palate, with a vestigial person attached. For them, the only activity that comes close to eating is talking about eating](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3ykEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA41&dq=foodie&hl=en&sa=X&ei=E5VDT_7oJYbe8QP25tyECA&ved=0CEIQ6AEwAjg8#v=onepage&q=foodie&f=false)

Comment: @Kris, *gourmand* might be more appropriate than *gourmet* in this context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers To me, *foodie* sounds more like interested in eating than relishing/ quantitative vs. qualitative. ;)

Comment: @Kris: Nah - *foodies* are definitely up for quality over quantity. I don't think *"foodie"* was a common term back in the days of [nouvelle cuisine](http://www.search.com/reference/Nouvelle_cuisine) (notorious for small portion sizes), but that's the sort of thing they would go for, imho.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you might have to content yourself with words or phrases for lovers of particular types of spirits. For example, an *œnophile* is a fine word for a *wine connoisseur*.

I don’t know of corresponding formal words for followers beer or whisky, but there are plenty of catchy circumlocutions for the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's not perfect, but it's quite fun: **liquorist**

See http://drinkmemag.com/2010/03/the-liqourist/ for some examples of the problem...

Comment: according to the OED, a liquorist is _one who makes liqueurs._

Answer (score 1):

Food & Wine magazine calls such folks *[cocktail connoisseurs](http://www.foodandwine.com/slideshows/gifts-for-cocktail-connoisseurs/4)*.

Also note this article that asks, *["Are You a Foodie or a Cocktail Connoisseur?"](http://www.eatdrinknola.com/are-you-a-foodie-or-a-cocktail-connoiseur/)*

If you're into the process of creating or formulating such drinks, you're a *[mixologist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mixology)*.

Comment: But you could love beer, and hold cocktails in contempt.

Comment: @slim Yeah, but the OP asked, "More concretely, I am looking for a term that describes a person that enjoys making or trying new, possibly eclectic drinks." Sounds like cocktails to me. (Hefeweizen is as eclectic as I get with beer.)

Answer (score 0):

How about [tippler](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tippler)?

> A habitual drinker; a bibber.

It could be considered pejorative depending on context, but I usually hear it used playfully. There's a fancy New York cocktail bar called [The Tippler](http://www.thetippler.com/about).